# Problem with MYSQL (INSERT)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i have model `question` with `text` and `token` fields. Want to add data into this via scaffold.

This is my question_ controller

```
  def create
    # @question = Question.new(params[:question])
      @question = Question.create(:text => params[:text], :security_token => Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(rand(1000000).to_s))
    render :json => @question.to_ext_json(:success => @question.save)
  end
```

When i press "ADD" button i get in console this:

```
  Question Create (0.0ms)   Mysql::Error: Column 'text' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `questions` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `text`, `security_token`) VALUES('2011-04-05 09:07:37', '2011-04-05 09:07:37', NULL, 'bf44551f11ce202b88d521a1826ab6db4254ce55')
```

Why COlumn 'text' can't be null?

Comment: It can't be null because table definition doesn't allow it to be null. Also, it's bad practice to use reserved words for column names in MySQL. Alter your table and remove "NOT NULL" part for that particular column definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the `text` column for the `questions` table with a `NOT NULL` constraint, and `params[:text]` is probably `nil`.

Since you used the scaffolding form `params[:question][:text]` returns the contents for `text`, **not** `params[:text]`!

Answer (score 0):

Because the column in the database table is defined as 'not null'?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an empty text value (NULL/nil) to a database field which has NOT NULL constraint defined. You need to either ensure, that text is never empty or release this constraint, allowing NULLable fiels in the MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add a validation in your model to verify if text is null. as such, you will be spared from this low level error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is nothing to do with ruby or rails, its just because you have defined the column as not null (.. as everybody says... :D ) , You might want to check your migration to see if you defined the column as not null there..

cheers

sameera